# Pass array of objects in query string node.js

Tags: node.js, url, query-string

If I want the Node.js query parser to parse an array, I can send this:

```
'?or=foo&or=bar' // gets me { or: ['foo', 'bar'] }
```

If I want an object I can do this:

```
'?or[foo]=bar' // gets me { or: {foo: 'bar'}}
```

But how do I get an array of objects? I'd like this output:

```
{ or: [{foo: 'bar'}, {bar: 'baz'}]}
```

Comment: Convert that to JSON and send it in the URL Encoded format

Comment: doesn't work. I just get this mess: { '{"or":': { '{"foo":"bar"},{"bar":"baz"}]': '' } }

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With the [`qs`](https://github.com/hapijs/qs) module, you can get the object you're looking for if you use this format:

`or[0][foo]=bar&or[1][bar]=baz`

Comment: Wow that worked without the module actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use options allowDots.

```
const stringParams = qs.stringify(params, {allowDots:true});
// myArray[0].name=MeWhit
qs.parse(stringParams , {allowDots: true});
// [{ name: MeWhit}]
```